# Displaying scrollable JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

I'm having trouble displaying a scrollable JTable in my contentPane, the table should be underneath the label, but nothing shows up. However, when I remove the scrollPane, the table is displayed.[image: Without scrollPane][image: With scrollPane]

```java
public void populateJTable(int resultCount, String[] closeNames, String[] closeCities) {
        String[] columnTitles = {"Brewery", "City"}; 
        String[][] data = new String[resultCount][columnTitles.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < closeNames.length; i++) {
            String tempBrewery = closeNames[i];
            String tempCity = closeCities[i];
            data[i][0] = tempBrewery;
            data[i][1] = tempCity;
        }

        table = new JTable(data, columnTitles);
        table.setBounds(20, 95, 580, 250);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane); 

    }
```

Comment: [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I remove the scrollPane, the table is displayed.

```
table.setBounds(20, 95, 580, 250);
```

Based on the above code it looks like you are using a null layout since you see the table.

However, when you add the table to the scrollpane, the scrollpane doesn't have a size so there is nothing to paint.

**Don't use a null layout!!!**

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Learn how to use them and the code will be easier to code and work better.

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

So now when you start using layout managers and you add a component to a visible GUI you need to `revalidate()` and repaint()` the panel that changed to invoke the layout manager on the panel. So you need to add:

```
contentPane.revalidate();
contentPane.repaint();
```

However, a better solution is to NOT keep creating a new JTable and JScrollPane. Instead you can create those components when you create the frame and add them to the frame.

Then when you do the search you just create a new TableModel with the search results and then you update the table using:

```
table.setModel( .... );
```

The table will repaint itself automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I did change to a FlowLayout instead of null. Another way I got the table to scroll was table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(550, 300));